# Knockout passing information from different models when using async ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

```
function UserInformation(data) {
    var self = this;
    this.AddressDetails = ko.observable(data.AddressDetails)
    // Client Details is array of ClientDetailInfo
    this.ClientDetails = ko.observableArray(data.ClientDetails);
    this.UserID = ko.observable(data.UserID);
}
function ClientDetailInfo(data) {
  this.Name = ko.observable(data.Name);
  this.Value = ko.observable(data.Value);
}
function InputFieldInfo(data) {
  this.DatabaseName = ko.observable(data.DatabaseName);
  this.Value = ko.observable(data.Value);
  // collab list gets filled when a user adds collaborators from the ui
  this.DatabaseName.CollabList = ko.observableArray([]);
}
function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  this.Name = ko.observable("");
  this.InputFields = ko.observable([]);

  //ajax request that maps data to InputFields

  //ajax request that maps data to User

}
```

I would like to take information from an index in the observableArray called ClientDetails where the name is "Perm_Collabs" and pass the value from that to the ObservableArray called CollabList in the InputFields where the DatabaseName is "Collaberators". Now I have this working in chrome the other browsers arnt as fast as it appears I might be having issues with attempting to put the data in fields that do not exist since the information is from ajax an therefore is currently async. So I attempted to do this with a subscription which works great in chrome and no where else. What is the best approach to this. As always if you need more info ask! Thanks Calvin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so there's a couple things that could help you to solve your cross browser issues.

First, this line.

```
this.DatabaseName.CollabList = ko.observableArray([]);
```

Are you checking if DatabaseName is `undefined`? Second, you are not getting the observable value of DatabaseName, just the function. You probably want this:

```
this.DatabaseName().CollabList = ko.observableArray([]);
```

Second, manual subscriptions. Sometimes, specially when loading data asynchronously, you don't want an X variable to be updated until Y is done finishing the update. For instance

```
this.myObservableArray = ko.observableArray([]);
this.myObservableArray.subscribe(function(newValueOfMyObservableArray) {
      $.ajax({..., success: function(data) {
         this.mySecondObservableArray(data);
      }})
}, this);
```

About obtaining the information from the ClientDetails, you only need to do a `foreach`, assuming you wired up all the variables properly.

```
function transferData(clientDetails, inputFields) {
var localClient = {};
ko.utils.arrayForEach(clientDetails(), function(client) {
    if (client.name === "Perm_Collabs") localClient = client;
});

ko.utils.arrayForEach(inputFields(), function(field) {
    if (field.databaseName === "Collaberators") {
        //Do whatever with localClient
    }
});

// Or if you need to replace in the same index you can skip the second loop
var index = clientDetails.indexOf(localClient); // Or do a forloop and save this step;
inputfields()[index].client = client;
}
```

Comment: This was helpful thanks for taking the time to answer my question.